# Remove appended `-1` from folders and files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have hundreds of URLs that have been indexed by Google and I need to resolve and redirect them. The pattern is like this:

```
www.mydomain.com/en/decor/somefolder-1/somepage-1.html?p=4
www.mydomain.com/it/somepage-1.html
www.mydomain.com/es/somefolder/anotherfolder-1/somepage.html
```

The CMS I use, Magento, has a rewrite module that fails sometimes and adds `-1` to folders and to `.html` files.

As you can see, I would need a rewrite rule that would take off the `-1` for the folders and the `-1` just before the `.html` for pages.

I would need it to permanent redirect (301) the incoming requests based on the system described above and rewrite them to:

```
www.mydomain.com/en/decor/somefolder/somepage.html?p=4
www.mydomain.com/it/somepage.html
www.mydomain.com/es/somefolder/anotherfolder/somepage.html
```

Help to accomplish this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)-1[\./](.*) $1$2 [R=302]
```

A `-1` followed by a period or a slash will be deleted. If the url contains more than one `-1`, this will be repeated until every `-1` is removed.
`[R=302]` is a flag used for defining an temporary redirect. This is only for testing purposes and can be replaced by `[R=301]` (for a permanent redirect) once you are sure that this solution solves your problem.